# Launch the "Associate a file type or protocol with a program" app from the command line

Tags: windows-10, file-association, startupscript, controlpanel

Every time I reboot Windows 10 build 1709, my web browser gets set back to Internet Explorer. This is just something I accept about life in the enterprise. However, we do have another approved browser, Google Chrome. So, I set my browser back to Google Chrome.

There doesn't seem to be a way to update the protocol associations from the command line. However, I can at startup launch the control panel applet that lets me set default programs with "control /name Microsoft.DefaultPrograms /page pageDefaultProgram". It unfortunately does nothing. The applet I have to launch is the "Associate a file type or protocol with a program" applet from "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Default Programs".

I cannot find the command to launch that applet. Do any of y'all know?

Comment: Try asking on superuser.com

Comment: I totally would? But, it's blocked by the firewall. On that note, it's funny that Elementary OS has its own StackExchange and Windows doesn't. I mean the Operating System family that runs over 80 % of all desktop systems. Windows Phone does. https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#technology-name